# Websocket connection with autobahn and twisted in python

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I'm trying to use twiested with autobahn to connect to a websocket server

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol


class OkcClient(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onOpen(self):
        #self.sendMessage(u"Hello, world!".encode('utf8'))
        self.sendMessage(u"{'event':'addChannel','channel':'ok_btcusd_future_ticker_this_week'}".encode('utf8'))
        self.sendMessage(u"{'event':'addChannel','channel':'ok_future_btcusd_kline_this_week_5min'}".encode('utf8'))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))


import sys
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
factory = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://real.okcoin.com:10440/websocket/okcoinapi")
factory.protocol = OkcClient

reactor.connectTCP("wss://real.okcoin.com/websocket/okcoinapi", 10440, factory)
reactor.run()
```

But the only thing I get out of this is the messages:

```
2014-11-18 11:45:39+0000 [-] Log opened.
2014-11-18 11:45:51+0000 [-] Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory instance at 0x106a0ccf8>
2014-11-18 11:46:04+0000 [-] Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory instance at 0x106a0ccf8>
```

No matter what I tried, the factory closes as soon as I do a `reactor.run()`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? If so, how was it solved?

Comment: No, I've abandoned it and tried other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`reactor.connectTCP` accepts as its first argument an IP address (or a hostname).  You passed it a URI.  It got confused and decided this must be a hostname, tried to resolve it, failed, and stopped the client factory.

Try passing `real.okcoin.com` instead of the full URI.  This can be resolved to an IP address (I assume) and the connection attempt will be able to proceed further.

Comment: I tried using `real.okcoin.com` for `reactor.connectTCP` and it now stops also right away but at least it shows: `2014-11-19 11:33:28+0000 [OkcClient,client] Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory instance at 0x1091a95f0>` So it looks like it went a bit further. But the logs don't say much about what is going on.

Comment: You can enable debug output in Autobahn like here: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo/client.py#L60

Comment: @jbssm seems you are trying to do secure WebSocket, which means you need to use `connectSSL` (or Twisted endpoints) .. look here: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_tls/client.py and here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn/twisted/websocket.py#L519